# Pikaday - mark or highlight certain dates

Tags: javascript, datepicker, pikaday

I am using pikaday and it is really decent datepicker. Is there possibility to mark or highlight certain dates? That could help users to distinguish "regular" dates from some "important" dates for them, at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array of dates to the `events` property:

> events array of dates that you would like to differentiate from regular days (e.g. ['Sat Jun 28 2017', 'Sun Jun 29 2017', 'Tue Jul 01 2017',])

https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#configuration

Comment: This configuration parameter does not work in Pikaday